# Magento: Apply Catalog Price Rule based on customer attribute

Tags: magento, attributes

I searched into custom modules, events and through `CatalogRule`'s code base but I can't figure out how to set a price for a product based on a customer attribute.

The only customer attribute available for filtering is the group, but with a different rule for each client, I would need to create one group for each customer... Not a good idea.

Is there even a way to achieve this? To use customer attributes in addition to product attributes?

Comment: add rules programattically with ur own conditions and customer attributes. if this all condition satisfy then and then the rule will be applied. have a look. http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-create-catalog-price-rule-programmatically/

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how I can filter on customer attributes with `catalogrule/rule` or `catalogrule/rule_condition_product` models. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty late to the party but I'll share anyways. This comes down to observing a rule and then injecting the conditions. Here is the method that dispatches the event we want:

```
Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine::getNewChildSelectOptions
```

and the event...

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_rule_condition_combine', array('additional' => $additional));
```

After that, your observer injects a new rule_condition model.

```
public function updateSalesRulesConditionsForCustomerAttributes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customerCondition = Mage::getModel('company/rule_condition_customer');
    $customerAttributes = $customerCondition->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();

    $attributes = array();

    foreach ($customerAttributes as $code=>$label) {
        $attributes[] = array('value'=>'company/rule_condition_customer|'.$code, 'label'=>$label);
    }

    $additional = $observer->getAdditional();
    $conditions = array(
        array('label'=>'Customer Attribute', 'value'=>$attributes)
    );

    $additional->setConditions($conditions);

    return $additional;
}
```

I wrote a post showing some more detail, including the rule model and how to specify the attributes. Have a look: https://www.peakcollective.com/magento-1-9-sales-rule-condition-customer-attribute/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Updated to provide more details and context.

Comment: Never too late... I don't remember how I got around this problem but I know I never found a real solution like this. Thanks a lot.